# How to change the text of a button which is defined in different xml file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

App gets data from an api and populates it in a recyclerview. The
recyclerview is in the **mainactivity.xml** which shows data in a cardview which is inflated from **datacard.xml**.

I want to change the text of a button which is in the datacard.xml from the MainActivity.java while clicking it.

I tried changing it from the DataCardAdapter and it works fine with similar code. But Its not happening from the MainActivity.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 final LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
 View dataCardView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.datacard, null);
 actionButton=(Button) dataCardView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAction);

    actionButton.setTag(ACTION_PLAY);
    actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String tag = (String) v.getTag();

            if (v.getTag() == ACTION_PLAY){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), " PLAY " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                actionButton.setText("PAUSE");
                actionButton.setTag(ACTION_PAUSE);
            }else if (v.getTag() == ACTION_PAUSE){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), " PAUSE " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                actionButton.setTag(ACTION_PLAY);
                actionButton.setText("PLAY");
            }
        }

    });
....
 public void ACTION_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
       ....
       ......
       .......

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DataAdapterClassList.add(GetDataModel);
    }

    if (array.length() != 0) {
        recyclerViewAdapter2 = new DataAdapter(DataAdapterClassList, this);
        recyclerView2.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter2);
    }
}
```

**mainactivity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorSplashText"
android:id="@+id/mainView">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**datacard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/Card"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/design_default_color_on_primary"
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
app:cardElevation="2dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constrainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:text="PLAY" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**DataCardAdapter**

```
public class DataCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    private static final String ACTION_PLAY = "play";
    private static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "pause";
    public List<EventsDataModel> eventsDataModels;
    public EventsAdapter(List<EventsDataModel> getDataAdapter, Context context) {
        super();
        this.eventsDataModels = getDataAdapter;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.datacard, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        final EventsDataModel dataAdapter = eventsDataModels.get(position);
        ......
        .......
       //  viewHolder.actionButton.setTag(ACTION_PLAY);

       // viewHolder.actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       //     @Override
       //     public void onClick(View v) {
       //         String tag = (String) v.getTag();

       //         if (v.getTag() == ACTION_PLAY){
       //             //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       //             Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), " PLAY " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       //             viewHolder.actionButton.setText("PAUSE");
       //             viewHolder.actionButton.setTag(ACTION_PAUSE);
       //         }else if (v.getTag() == ACTION_PAUSE){
       //             Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), " PAUSE " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       //             viewHolder.actionButton.setTag(ACTION_PLAY);
       //             viewHolder.actionButton.setText("PLAY");
       //         }
       //     }
       // });

    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private Button actionButton;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            actionButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAction);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: pass that text with intent to another activity and use incoming intent to get text and set it to your button.

Comment: another activity? I just have one activity.

Comment: Where is your adapter?

Comment: @PratikButani adapter added. see the commented code. it works if uncommented

Comment: If its working then why you want to call from Activity. and Its but obvious thing that you cant use button directly from activity. You have to create interface for that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it this way. You should store that information in adapter.

RecyclerView will reuse (recycle) views to display data. This is why it is called recycler view.

Lets say you clicked first item and changed its state to PAUSE (PAUSE is stored in textview's tag). Then you scroll down and recyclerView instead of inflating another view it will reuse first view (as first item is no longer visible). So it will override the tag and text of this textView with new data.

When you will scroll back to the first item it will put data back again but it will use data from adapter.

The solution is to store that state in the adapter. And invalidate item when you click it (so it will redraw that item).

So when you click item you should do something more or less like that:

```
     adapter.items.get(position).state="PLAY"
     adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
```

You can store position in tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from `DataCardAdapter`

create one method in `DataCardAdapter` where you have an axis of button so you can change the name of button ,

```
public changeButtonName(String buttonName){
//Here you can set new button name
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

call this method from `MainActivity` by using Object of `Adapter` , please first check adapter object should not be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access adapter's view from activity if you have position of item in activity like below code

```
 if(recyclerViewThemes.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(Your item position here)!=null)
                    {
                        View tempView = recyclerViewThemes.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(Your item position here).itemView;

                        Button btn = tempView.findViewById(R.id.btn);

                        btn.setText("Your text here");
                    }
                     recyclerViewThemes.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(i);//notify your adapter
```